# How to check if application exited or closed android?

Tags: android, android-service

I want to perform some activities like clearing cache, singletons clearing etc. I will write all this code in Service which will be background but I need this service to be triggered only when application is closed or exited.

I cant put my code to statrt service in onDestroy of activity as whenever i will move between my activities it will call onDestroy of previous activity.

How to know if application is exited.

Example will really help.

Thanks.

Comment: `onStop()` and `onDestroy()` are the places to check whether your app is there or not in memory.

Comment: Better use the `onDestroy()` override

Comment: Using a `Service` to do this is bad design and a pointless use of extra code (which may or may not run correctly anyway).You need to save data as you go along and save state of application components at the point they are either paused or stopped.

Comment: @FrankN.Stein : The `onDestroy` method of `Activity` is not guaranteed to be called and should never be relied on for saving data or state.

Comment: @Squonk : But `onStop()` will fire at every device rotation...

Comment: Here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12121783/saving-android-application-data-on-app-exit is similar thread. Read accepted answer.

Comment: @FrankN.Stein : So what is your point? Change of device orientation will cause an `Activity` to be destroyed and recreated - in this case `onDestroy()` will be called but under other circumstances `onDestroy` may not be called. As a result, relying on `onDestroy` for saving of data or state isn't a safe option.

Comment: @Squonk You're right. I didn't think that `onDestroy()` was called upon rotation too. Just upon app termination.

Comment: @all i want to handle when application is exited not when activity is destroyed

Answer (score 2):

The [ActivityManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.html) should be what you are looking for.

For example see [here](http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=android.app.ActivityManager)

Answer (score 1):

in your main activity, capture the "back" key and check for [Activity.isTaskRoot()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#isTaskRoot%28%29) whether it is the last one. If yes, your app is going to "exit", then do some communication with your service.

please note pressing the Home key doesn't mean to "exit" your app