# How to save a integer value when the program is closed in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-activity

Suppose i have an integer i and whenever I press a button, the value of i increases by 1. I want the app the save the value of i when the user exits the app and when the user opens the app again, the number displayed should be the one which was saved.

Comment: You can use SharedPreferences http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Next time you should search first: [save variables after quitting application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11688689/save-variables-after-quitting-application)

To your question. There is something called `SharedPreferences` in Android, to save data like your value.

Get the variable in your `onCreate` with

```
SharedPreferences mPrefs = getSharedPreferences("label", 0);
int mInt = mPrefs.getInteger("tag", 0); // 0 = value if var not found
```

and later edit the variable with

```
SharedPreferences.Editor mEditor = mPrefs.edit();
mEditor.putInteger("tag", value_of_var).commit();
```

in this case `"tag"` is your variable name, the name is not important as long it is the same while saving and editing.