# how can I save objects after closing my Android application?

Tags: java, android, close-application

I am making a small game and I want to **save all the variables (objects and basic types)** when closing the app to be able to load the saved game later on.

Here are some of the variables:

```
    String playerName;
    Duration time;
    Item[] inventory=new Item[20]; //enum
    int inventoryTotalItems=0;
```

It is basically the same situation than [save variables after quitting application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11688689/save-variables-after-quitting-application/11688753) or [How can I save an activity state using the save instance state?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/151777/how-can-i-save-an-activity-state-using-the-save-instance-state) but what I want to save are Objects, so **I am not sure I can use the preferences or the Bundle** for that.
I also will want to store more than one preference to be able to load different saved games. Can I do this with onPause() and onResume()?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this in your dependencies(in build.gradle file):

```
implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.9'
```

And then you can save objects like this:

```
SharedPreferences sp = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor pe = sp.edit();
Gson gson = new Gson();
String j = gson.toJson(myObj);
pe.putString("MyObject", j);
pe.apply();
```

And when you want to access the object later:

```
SharedPreferences sp = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
Gson gson = new Gson();
String j = sp.getString("MyObject", null);
MyObject myObj = gson.fromJson(j, MyObject.class);
```

I think you should save in onPause().

Comment: can I use this to save the state of a game?

Comment: If it's related with just some variables and objects, yes. The way may change in complex cases.